# How is Hyperledger Composer REST server being updated after changing the blockchain model?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed the instructions https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/interacting/

I saw the APIs on Hyperledger Composer REST server.

I then updated the model, script and ACL. The Deployment was successful, but the APIs were still the same, so I ran this script again - no change:

```
./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --business-network-card admin@perishable-network
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The rest server dynamically downloads the business network definition, so it sees and displays the interface for the current business network. If it is still the same then your ugrade to your new business network has not happened.

Comment: @david_k Added two screenshots. It looked like the business network update (clicked on deploy) was successful. I could see the new original and the new participants and assets on the test tab (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31080/test, 1st screenshot). Any idea, why they don't show up on the APIs (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31090/explorer/#/, 2nd screenshot) like on this image: https://github.com/IBM/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/raw/master/Blockchain/screenshots/API.png ?

Comment: maybe try deleting the composer rest server first using the delete script before trying to create it again ?

Comment: I ran delete_all and started from scratch, this time I modified model, script, acl and before I started the compose rest server. Maybe delete_composer-rest-server.sh & create_composer-rest-server.sh would have worked out as well.